# How to use SDK for HTC EVO 3D?

Tags: android, opengl-es, sdk, stereoscopy

Has anyone tried to write OpenGL apps with the SDK, especially with Eclipse?

I tried, but I can't compile the examples.

How can I use the HTC SDK? For non-3D handsets it's possible to render OpenGL applications to a stereoscopic anaglyph for viewing.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got the SDK from HTC running.. the 4 Example Apps are working fine but not that good. 
I will try to combine the 3D Renderer from the HTC 3D SampleProjects with the min3d renderer. 
So i can use the min3d framework to create simple GL apps / anims etc. with 3D Stereo. Jeay!

Answer (score 1):

For HTC S3D Sample Activities, you should first Import them on Eclipse, then you should either change the "Properties->Android->Project Build Target" to HTC OpenSense SDK or add the jar file of OpenSense from "Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries(Tab)->Add External JARs" and then you should locate the OpenSense from "SDK_folder->add-ons->..htc_folder..".

Both of these worked for me.